# Is there a way to store a variable data type in a column in Room

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I just started a new job and the first major task I was assigned was to upgrade our app from using a custom SQLiteHelper implementation to using Room.

Currently we have a table that is literally just a table of Key/Value pairs where the value is variable (ie sometimes the variable is a String, long, int or boolean) [always a primitive type] but stored as a String. This was accomplished by having the POJO object structured like this:

```
public class KeyValue {
    private static final String TAG = KeyValues.class.getSimpleName();
    Map<String, String> _map;

    public Iterable<? extends Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
        return _map.entrySet();
    }

    public void put(String key, Object value){
        _map.put(key, val == null ? null : val.toString());
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        return _map.get(key);
    }

    public String getString(String key, String defaultValue) {
        String value = getString(key);
        return value == null ? defaultValue : value;
    }

    public int getInt(String key) {
        String value = _map.get(key);
        if (value == null) return 0;
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
           Reporter.w(TAG, "Could not parse int %s : %s", key, value)
           return 0;
        }
    }

    public long getLong(String key) {
        return getLong(key, 0L);
    }

    public long getLong(String key, long defaultValue) {
        String value = _map.get(key);
        if (value == null) return defaultValue;
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            Reporter.w(TAG, "Could not parse long %s : %s", key, value)
            return 0L;
        }
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        String value = _map.get(key);
        if (value == null) return defaultValue;
        if ("true".equals(value)) return true;
        if ("false".equals(value)) return false;
        Reporter.w(TAG, "Could not parse boolean %s : %s", key, value)
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

This is basically treated the same as shared preferences, the keys are all constants in the app and not data pulled from our servers and the values are all primitives.

I don't have the time right now to convert this section of the code to shared presences because my hands are full with the Room implementation. So I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this without using string conversions.

My current new object that i am using looks like this (I am really just trying to not do the string converting):

```
@Entity(tableName = "key_values", indices = [Index(value = ["_key"], unique = true)])
class KeyValue {

    private val TAG = KeyValue::class.java.simpleName

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_key")
    var key = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    var value = ""

    fun getValueAsInt(): Int {
        try {
            return value.toInt()
        } catch (exception: NumberFormatException) {
            Reporter.w(TAG, "Could not parse int %s : %s", key, value)
            throw exception
        }

    }

    fun getValueAsLong(): Long {
        try {
            return value.toLong()
        } catch (exception: NumberFormatException) {
            Reporter.w(TAG, "Could not parse long %s : %s", key, value)
            throw exception
        }
    }

    fun getValueAsBool(): Boolean {
        if (value.equals("true", true) || value.equals("false", true)) {
            return value.toBoolean()
        } else {
            throw ClassCastException("Not a boolean")
        }
    }
}
```

I really want to just be able to do something like:

```
    int value = keyValue.getValue();
```

or

```
    long value = keyValue.getValue();
```

instead of

```
    int value = keyValue.getValueAsInt();
```

and

```
    long value = keyValue.getValueAsLong();
```

Also as a side note I am implementing Room in Kotlin but a lot of these methods will be used in Java classes as we have not started converting old code into Kotlin yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there was a way to get what I was going for so I ended up using the "getValueAs" functions.